# Parsing error (android) no element found

Tags: android

This is the code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/quickscreen"
/>
```

It will not generate R.java because of it. Any ideas?

Comment: I got rid of the drawable and dimen and it did nothing. I also checked and they do exist.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, try disabling "Build Automatically", and then cleaning your project. Sometimes I even need to restart Eclipse before building the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/quickscreen" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Note the closing `>` after the `android:background` attribute.

Comment: AFAIK, both are same ways to close tags -your's and in the question.

Comment: @VedPrakash : I agree with you but the OP's way of doing it isn't the usual way to construct a `LinearLayou` in a layout file. I'm ready to be proved wrong if it doesn't fix the OP's problem but I just thought it would be worth a try as that's how I'd do it and I'd never use the OP's way for a `LinearLayout`. For one thing it makes more sense to properly define the start and end elements of any `ViewGroup` in a layout file.